# Convert Time-String using joda-time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have to following time-string: "23.02.2015 14:06:30 +01:00" which I want to print. The printed result should be: "23.02.2015 **15**:06:30". 
After some research I just found a solution which I dont think of to be a good idea. Perhabs anyone of you has some conclusions on how to do this right? The conversion should be done with joda-time.
Thanks in advance.

** Update due to explaining difference for the mentioned dublicate:
My first approach was just like mentioned in [Java : how to add 10 mins in my Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time) to add or remove the hours manually. What I tried to underline is that I dont think of this as a good idea because this could be dangerous if the input string will change (much space for possible errors). So I was wondering if joda-time has some functionality that would make my life easier adn which I didnt notice so far.

Comment: Which is your solution? Why don't you think it is a good idea?

Comment: "23.02.2015 14:06:30 +01:00" is the same time (instant) as "23.02.2015 15:06:30 +02:00", so do you want to manipulate the timezone offset? Do you else understand that a positive offset has to be subtracted to get UTC-time?

Comment: _updated my question and added some explanation on what I did so far_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime` class `plusxx()` methods](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTime = "23.02.2015 14:06:30 +01:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

        DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTime);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dtfOut.print(jodatime));


        DateTime resultDateTime = jodatime.plusHours(1);
        System.out.println(dtfOut.print(resultDateTime));
    }
```

And the output is;

```
23.02.2015 08:36:30
23.02.2015 09:36:30
```

Result date isn't wrong, for more information about this subject please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687940/java-and-joda-time-date-wrong-value).

For fixed dates, I added  time zone with  `withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Prague" )` ;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTime = "23.02.2015 14:06:30 +01:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

        DateTime jodatime = dtf.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Prague" ) ).parseDateTime(dateTime);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dtfOut.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Prague" ) ).print(jodatime));


        DateTime resultDateTime = jodatime.plusHours(1);
        System.out.println(dtfOut.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Prague" ) ).print(resultDateTime));
    }
```

And the output is ;

```
23.02.2015 14:06:30
23.02.2015 15:06:30
```

Comment: hi, thanks for yout post. so there is no other solution then adding / removing the hours manually?

Comment: Common usage of this to use plusxxx methods, of course you can try some other ways but I think that is the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

I also have noticed this strange situation when working and converting to `Joda Time`. What I did is just substract one hour from the `Joda Time` like this:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime([YOUR_JAVA.UTIL.DATE]);

Date result = new Date(dt1).minus(Seconds.seconds(3600)).getSeconds() * 1000);
```